# pip install for windows running into anaconda error

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I am trying to pip install pyrtlsdr for the software defined radio RTL-SDR (RTL2832U), but am running into issues with anaconda I believe. I am receiving two errors in cmd, although I am getting the same response through cygwin and cmder. I am running the following command:

```
pip install pyrtlsdr
```

However, when I run this command, I see the following error:

```
pip install pyrtlsdr
Collecting pyrtlsdr
  Using cached pyrtlsdr-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyrtlsdr
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", 
  line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", 
line 317, in run
  prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 
742, in install
  **kwargs
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", 
line 831, in install
  self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", 
line 1032, in move_wheel_files
  isolated=self.isolated,
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 346, 
in 
move_wheel_files
  clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 317, 
in 
 clobber
 ensure_dir(destdir)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", 
line 83, in ensure_dir
  os.makedirs(path)
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
  mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program 
Files\\Anaconda2\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrtlsdr-0.2.4.dist-info'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' 
command.
```

What exactly is wrong here? I do not know how to force privileges in this file that I think is causing issues, additionally, I also do not know why I am receiving the same error when I run the suggested upgrade in this error.

Comment: It's telling you to upgrade pip, which you should. If you believe that's more problems then that, run cmd as admin

Comment: I see that and tried to upgrade pip, but when I run the suggested command, I get an identical error.

Comment: From a comment that got deleted:So I performed the following to upgrade anaconda: "conda update conda" and then "conda update anaconda". After this, I tried to run the command and ran into the same "Access is denied" error for both pip install pyrtlsdr as well as "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"

Comment: The upgrade pip thing is just a warning imho. This looks like an access-rights problem / OS-problem. But no idea what went wrong with your setup. Is the user using pip the one who installed anaconda (or was anaconda installed only for some different user)? Also: is pip the correct one? -> system-paths (and not an old vanilla-python pip; not sure if it would matter though).

Comment: @sascha is there any particular reason this would give me the same error for trying to upgrade pip? Is there a way to force sudo privileges in cmd on windows?

Comment: Yes, Run cmd as admin (right click on cmd.exe -> run as admin on my sys).  But normally this kind of setup is wrong. Anaconda should be installed as non-admin for some user imho.

Comment: Yes, this is through my personal computer, so I was the one who installed anaconda as well as the software packages that I am needing to access. I will check on the system paths really quick.

Comment: Okay, with your help @sascha, I got it figured out. I guess Anaconda defaults to admin only, so when I installed pip through C:\Python27\Scripts and had it added to my path, nothing on my OS had any reference of this because Anaconda was the default compiler for python. After entering cmd as admin and copying the https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py file to the anaconda folder and running it through python, it got added to the Scripts file in the anaconda source folder and it compiled to the Scripts file there. I added this to my path and pip works fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the cmd line as administrator, this should give write privilege to C drive.